# Multiprocessing best practice in this case?

Tags: python, optimization, multiprocessing

I currently have a working multiprocessing setup in my code, but I am not exactly pleased with it, and was wondering whether anyone could suggest a better way of doing it.

```
def fnc_to_parallelize(args):
    file, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5 = args
    return

tasks = [(file,arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5) for file in files_to_run]
pool = mp.Pool(nparallel)
for _ in tqdm.tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(fnc, tasks), total=len(tasks)):
    pass
```

So what this does is run a function in parallel that operates on a file, with a set of input parameters, where most of the parameters are never changing.
I generally have 100k-500k files I need to run on, but the time it takes to run on a file can be very different (some files takes less than a second while other take 10 minutes).

What I don't like about my script:

1. I currently have to create this tasks list with 300k-500k elements, each of which contains n arguments that are the same for all of them (This is not really a big issue, it just strikes me as ugly).
2. my fnc_to_parallelize can only take one argument, which I then have to unpack inside the function. This seems really ugly, since I also would like to be able to call this function in a non-parallel way, where I just specify the arguments, but currently I have to do that in an unintuitive way where the arguments are stored in a tuple or dict first.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how I could make this parallelization in a better way? I would especially like a suggestion such that I could have fnc_to_parallelize as:

```
def fnc_to_parallelize(file, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5):
    return
```

since this is how I would normally keep this function if it wasn't being used in parallelization, but imap_unordered doesn't allow this as far as I know, and I'm not sure what I can replace it with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module instead,which provides a higher level API for making use of multiprocessing pools:

```
import concurrent.futures
import time
import random


def fnc_to_parallelize(file, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5):
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 30))
    return file


files_to_run = ["file{}".format(x) for x in range(100000)]
pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=100)
args = ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3", "arg4", "arg5"]
tasks = [pool.submit(fnc_to_parallelize, file, *args) for file in files_to_run]

for task in concurrent.futures.as_completed(tasks):
    print("result:", task.result())
```

Comment: It worked, but it seems problematic when the number of tasks becomes very large.
I am currently trying to run this with 300000 tasks/submits and just the submit statement has currently been hanging for 10 minutes without even getting to the actual tasks yet.
I guess I should try to explore a way to not submit all jobs at the same time

Comment: Maybe you can submit an initial batch of tasks, then submit new tasks in the `for` loop as existing tasks complete.