# Multiprocessing best practice for large number of tasks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, python-multiprocessing

A few days ago I asked what the best way to do multiprocessing for my particular problem would be: [Multiprocessing best practice in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71329049/multiprocessing-best-practice-in-this-case/71329212#71329212)

And based on that I got the following:

```
nparallel = set_number_of_cores(nparallel)
pool = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=nparallel)

args = [(f"{path_in}/{pdb_id}.pdb", f"{path_calc}/{pdb_id}", path_FFT, path_finished,
         path_failed, LOG, remove_path_tmp_on_finish) for pdb_id in ids_to_run]
tasks = [pool.submit(relax_fnc,*arg) for arg in args]
for task in tqdm.tqdm(concurrent.futures.as_completed(tasks), total=len(tasks),
smoothing=0.0, desc='Energy Minimization on Folder'):
    pass
```

This method seemed fine when I was testing it out on smaller samples.
But now I'm trying to run it on the actual problem and just hangs at the:

```
tasks = [pool.submit(relax_fnc,*arg) for arg in args]
```

I guess the problem is that I am submitting too many jobs. Is there any way of easily fixing this? I guess I could create an initial pool of jobs maybe 10 times the number of processes I use, and then just dynamically submit more tasks as they complete, but that doesn't seem very pretty.

So I'm hoping someone else have a better solution.

(I'm currently running it with 300k tasks)

Comment: The only problem submitting a huge number of jobs would be for the processing to take a really long time to complete. Multiprocessing is no magic bullet. Perhaps you should make each task do more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following class, `BoundedQueueProcessPoolExecutor`, will by default will ensure that the processing pool's task queue will not have more than `N` tasks enqueued waiting to run where `N` by default is the pool size (but you can initialize an instance of this class with the *max_waiting_tasks* keyword argument and specify any positive integer).

This class therefore prevents you from creating all the future instances more or less at once but only as execution proceeds and tasks terminate. Therefore, the use of the `as_completed` method becomes less useful and instead you should use a completion callback function as demonstrated in the following program:

```py
import multiprocessing
import concurrent.futures
import tqdm


class BoundedQueuePoolExecutor:
    def __init__(self, semaphore):
        self.semaphore = semaphore

    def release(self, future):
        self.semaphore.release()

    def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        self.semaphore.acquire()
        future = super().submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)
        future.add_done_callback(self.release)
        return future

class BoundedQueueProcessPoolExecutor(BoundedQueuePoolExecutor, concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor):
    def __init__(self, *args, max_waiting_tasks=None, **kwargs):
        concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if max_waiting_tasks is None:
            max_waiting_tasks = self._max_workers
        elif max_waiting_tasks < 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid negative max_waiting_tasks value: {max_waiting_tasks}')
        BoundedQueuePoolExecutor.__init__(self, multiprocessing.BoundedSemaphore(self._max_workers + max_waiting_tasks))


def worker(x):
    # simulate taking time:
    import time
    time.sleep(1)
    return x ** 2

def my_callback(future):
    bar.update()
    # This demo is storing results but yours may not be
    # storing 300K results:
    results.append(future.result())

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    params = list(range(1, 101))
    results = []
    bar = tqdm.tqdm(total=len(params))
    with BoundedQueueProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for x in params:
            future = executor.submit(worker, x)
            future.add_done_callback(my_callback)
```

**Second Demo with 300,000 tasks (results not stored)**

```
import concurrent.futures
import tqdm


class BoundedQueuePoolExecutor:
    def __init__(self, semaphore):
        self.semaphore = semaphore

    def release(self, future):
        self.semaphore.release()

    def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        self.semaphore.acquire()
        future = super().submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)
        future.add_done_callback(self.release)
        return future

class BoundedQueueProcessPoolExecutor(BoundedQueuePoolExecutor, concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor):
    def __init__(self, *args, max_waiting_tasks=None, **kwargs):
        concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if max_waiting_tasks is None:
            max_waiting_tasks = self._max_workers
        elif max_waiting_tasks < 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid negative max_waiting_tasks value: {max_waiting_tasks}')
        BoundedQueuePoolExecutor.__init__(self, multiprocessing.BoundedSemaphore(self._max_workers + max_waiting_tasks))


def worker(x):
    return x ** 2

def my_callback(future):
    bar.update()

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    params = range(1, 300_001)
    results = []
    bar = tqdm.tqdm(total=300_000)
    with BoundedQueueProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for x in params:
            future = executor.submit(worker, x)
            future.add_done_callback(my_callback)
```

**Note**

Neither of these demos are actually suitable candidates for multiprocessing, i.e. they would run much faster as serial programs.